# multiple loops google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am currently working in GAS to create and optimize a search function based on multiple criteria.

I have code that works, but it is inconsistent on whether or not the function call will time-out before the search is completed.

```js
    //Top level function to run the sub-level OD, ID, End Ring, Pusher, and Bushing Length functions
    function toolSearch(od, id, mat) {

      var od1 = parseFloat(od);
      var id1 = parseFloat(id);
      var inc = .25; //change to 0 when standardized bushings are implemented
      var passOutput = [];
      var failOutput = ["Tooling Unavailable", "Contact CPI Stafford Materials Engineer"];

      if (od1 > 49 || id1 > 46)
        return failOutput;

      //If statement to determine amount of end rings required based on OD shell size and material
      if (mat == "Hot Mold" && od < 10)
        var qER = 4;
      else
        qER = 2;

      //Initial tooling search         
      var od2 = toolSearchOD(od1);
      var id2 = toolSearchID(id1);
      var er = toolSearchER(od2, id2);
      var ps = toolSearchPS(od2);
      var wall = wallCall(od2, id2);

      //return variables must be parsed from strings to integers and decimals
      od2 = parseFloat(od2);
      id2 = parseFloat(id2);
      er = parseInt(er);
      ps = parseInt(ps);
      wall = parseFloat(wall);

      //Remove comments when standardized bushings are implemented 
      /*if(id>10)
           {inc = .5;}
      else
           {inc = .25;}*/

      //If statement to check for pusher and end ring requirments before moving into for loop
      if (er < qER || ps < 1) {

        //For loop to find OD and ID shells, the required quantity of end rings, and the pusher
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) { //Loop is set at 75 in order to prevent 30 second function time out. May need to be adjusted.

          od2 += inc;
          od2 = toolSearchOD(od2);
          od2 = parseFloat(od2);
          wall = wallCall(od2, id2);
          wall = parseFloat(wall);
          er = toolSearchER(od2, id2);
          er = parseInt(er);
          ps = toolSearchPS(od2);
          ps = parseInt(ps);

          if (wall > 3) {
            id2 -= inc
            id2 = toolSearchID(id2);
            id2 = parseFloat(id2);
            od2 = od1 - inc;
            od2 = parseFloat(od2);
            er = toolSearchER(od2, id2);
            er = parseInt(er);
          }

          if (er >= qER && ps >= 1)
            break;

        }
      }



      //A final check to make sure that the variable is parsed to an integer or decimal
      od2 = parseFloat(od2);
      id2 = parseFloat(id2);
      er = parseInt(er);
      ps = parseInt(ps);
      wall = parseFloat(wall);
      var blength = bLength(mat, od2, id2); //Bushing Length function input/output 

      //If statement to check if requirements have been met to return the proper information
      if (er < qER || ps < 1 || wall > 3) {
        return failOutput;
      } else {
        passOutput = [od2, id2, blength, er, ps, wall];
        return passOutput;
      }

    }


//A final check to make sure that the variable is parsed to an integer or decimal
od2 = parseFloat(od2);
id2 = parseFloat(id2);
er = parseInt(er);
ps = parseInt(ps);
wall = parseFloat(wall);
var blength = bLength(mat,od2, id2);  //Bushing Length function input/output 

//If statement to check if requirements have been met to return the proper information
if(er < qER || ps < 1 || wall > 3){
Logger.log("FAILURE TO FIND SIZE " + passOutput);
return failOutput;}

else{
passOutput = [od2,id2, blength,er, ps, wall];
return passOutput;}

}

//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function for searching the shell OD inventory, based on the updated OD from toolSearch

function toolSearchOD(od) {
var range = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangeSHOD');//Call to data in cache
range =  Utilities.parseCsv(range);//All returns from cache need to be parsed from a CSV format to a horizontal array with a permanent row of zero
var size = lastRow("Shell Inventory");//Call to sub-function to determine index of last row of the sheet with data in it.
var found = 0;
     
od = parseFloat(od);//A built in check to make sure that the variable is parsed to a decimal
var inc = .25;//change to 0 when standardized bushings are implemented

//Remove comments when standardized bushings are implemented 
/*if(od>10)
     {var inc = .5;}
else
     {inc = .25;}*/
     
while (found != 1){     
            
            for(var j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(range[0][j] == od){
                
                 od = range[0][j];
                 found = 1;
                 }           
            }
         if(found != 1)   
         od+=inc;
         }
   return od;
   }  
  
//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function for searching the shell OD inventory, based on the updated ID from toolSearch
function toolSearchID(id) {

var range = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangeSHID');
range =  Utilities.parseCsv(range);
var size = lastRow("Shell Inventory");
var found = 0;

id = parseFloat(id);
var inc = .25;//change to 0 when standardized bushings are implemented

//Remove comments when standardized bushings are implemented 
 /*if(id>10)
     {var inc = .5;}
else
     {inc = .25;}*/
     
while (found != 1){     
            
            for(var j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(range[0][j] == id){
                
                 id = range[0][j];
                 found = 1;
                 }           
            }
         if(found != 1)   
         id-=inc;
         }
   return id;
   }  

//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function for searching the end ring inventory, based on the updated ID and OD values from toolSearchID and toolSearchOD.

function toolSearchER(od,id) {

var rangeOD = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangeEROD');
var rangeID = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangeERID');
var rangeQTY = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangeERQTY');
rangeOD = Utilities.parseCsv(rangeOD);
rangeID = Utilities.parseCsv(rangeID);
rangeQTY = Utilities.parseCsv(rangeQTY);
var size = lastRow("End Ring Inventory");
var erQTY = 0;

od = parseFloat(od);
id = parseFloat(id);

 for(var j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(rangeID[0][j] == id && rangeOD[0][j] == od){
                  
                   erQTY += parseInt(rangeQTY[0][j]);
                   
                 }  
}
                


return erQTY;
}

//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function for searching the end ring inventory, based on the updated ID and OD values from toolSearchID and toolSearchOD.

function toolSearchPS(od) {

var rangeQTY = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangePSQTY');
var rangeOD = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangePSOD');
rangeOD = Utilities.parseCsv(rangeOD);
rangeQTY = Utilities.parseCsv(rangeQTY);
var size = lastRow("Pusher Inventory");
var psQTY = 0;

od = parseFloat(od);

od -= .25;

 for(var j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(rangeOD[0][j] == od){
                
                 psQTY = rangeQTY[0][j];
                 }
            }
          

return psQTY;
}

//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function to calculate bushing wall size based on updated OD and ID inputs from toolSearch, toolSearchOD, and toolSearchID

function wallCall(od,id){

var wall;

wall = (od-id)/2; 

return wall;
}

//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function that puts all required data into a Google cache for more efficent processing. Cache time limit is 1 hour

function cache(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheetSH = ss.getSheetByName("Shell Inventory");
var sheetSHL = sheetSH.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
var sheetER = ss.getSheetByName("End Ring Inventory");
var sheetPS = ss.getSheetByName("Pusher Inventory");
var rangeSHOD = sheetSH.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
var rangeSHID = sheetSH.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
var rangeERQTY = sheetER.getRange("H2:H").getValues();
var rangeEROD = sheetER.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
var rangeERID = sheetER.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
var rangePSQTY = sheetPS.getRange("G2:G").getValues();
var rangePSOD = sheetPS.getRange("B2:B").getValues();


CacheService.getScriptCache().put('rangeSHOD',rangeSHOD,3600);
CacheService.getScriptCache().put('rangeSHID',rangeSHID,3600);
CacheService.getScriptCache().put('sheetSHL' ,sheetSHL,3600);
CacheService.getScriptCache().put('rangeERID',rangeERID,3600);
CacheService.getScriptCache().put('rangeEROD',rangeEROD,3600);
CacheService.getScriptCache().put('rangeERQTY',rangeERQTY,3600);
CacheService.getScriptCache().put('rangePSQTY',rangePSQTY,3600);
CacheService.getScriptCache().put('rangePSOD',rangePSOD,3600);
}

//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function to calculate the index of last row of data for a sheet

function lastRow(sheetName){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var size=sheet.getLastRow();

return size;
}

//****************************************************************************************
//Sub-function to calculate bushing length based on OD and ID shell lengths and type of material

function bLength (mat,od, id){

var rangeID = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangeSHID');
var rangeOD = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('rangeSHOD');
var rangeL = CacheService.getScriptCache().get('sheetSHL');
rangeID =  Utilities.parseCsv(rangeID);
rangeOD =  Utilities.parseCsv(rangeOD);
rangeL =  Utilities.parseCsv(rangeL);
var size = lastRow("Shell Inventory");
var lengthID = 0;
var lengthOD = 0;
var blength = 0;

id = parseFloat(id);
od = parseFloat(od);


//Find ID shell length
            for(var j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(rangeID[0][j] == id){
                
                 lengthID = rangeL[0][j];
                 }           
            }
         
 
 found = 0;
//Find OD shell length
  
            
            for(var j=0;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(rangeOD[0][j] == od){
                
                 lengthOD = rangeL[0][j];
                
                 }           
          
 
if(lengthID == 18){
    blength = "5 inches *Configuration not recommended*.";}

else if (lengthOD == 18)
    blength = "5 inches";
    
else if(mat == "Hot Mold"){
    blength = "6 inches";}
  
else
    blength = "9 inches";

return blength;
}
}
function matType(mat){

var hot = 0;
var matType;

switch (mat){
    
      case 620:
        hot = 1;
        break;
     case 603:        
        hot = 1;
        break;
     case 604:        
        hot = 1;
        break;
     case 611:        
        hot = 1;
        break;
     case 605:        
        hot = 1;
        break;
     case 608:
        hot = 1;
        break;
     case 580:
        hot = 1;
        break;
     case 607:
        hot = 1;
        break;        
     default:
        break;
  }

if (hot == 1)
  matType = "Hot Mold";
else
  matType = "Cold Mold";
  
  return matType;

}
```

Yes I know it's clunky. The "for" loop requirement is there to keep the script from timing out but it is far from effective and I know there is a better way.

The data is on 3 separate sheets and their is a function that caches all the relevant data to try and limit the amount of calls to the sheet, which helped, but not enough.

How can I make this code more efficient? I need to add more criteria which will require more looping to find the correct set of tooling for a job and I'm afraid this will cause the top level function to exceed the function call time very quickly.

Comment: This is more of a "Code Review" question.  And it looks like you haven't included all of the code.  Is there a `toolSearchOD()` function?  Are other functions being called?  If you want to check execution times of server operations, you can look at the Execution Transcript.  If this is not about server execution times, then it might be more of a JavaScript question than Apps Script.

Comment: No this is just the top level function, there are quite a few smaller functions that make this one up. when those functions are called individually there is no problem, but having a recursive loop that calls them over and over again is what is causing the execution time of this top level function to time out. So this is really more of an optimisation  question.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that could be made to run faster by structuring it in a different way, or changing something.  Reading and writing data takes time.  Processing large amounts of data takes time.  There is nothing in your question that shows reading or writing data.  There is nothing in your question that indicates the amount of data.  The functions that are called, aren't shown, so we have no idea how long each one of those functions run.  The typical error that people make is to use `getValues()` for single cell or one row of data instead of getting data from an entire sheet.

Comment: All code and functions have now been added to the first post for clarification